# how to center a div without width?

Tags: css, html, center

hello i would like to know if it is possible to center a div without having a width. because of two different versions of a container depending from language settings with different widths i would like to center it dynamically.

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

is not working without any settings of width.

so the structure is simple:

```
<div id="container">
        <div id="list">
            <span class="up">text large</span>
            <ul class="navigation">
                <li>one</li>
                <li>|</li>
                <li>two</li>
                <li>|</li>
                <li>three</li>
                <li>|</li>
                <li>four</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
</div>
```

and the css:

```
.wrapper #container  {
    width: 960px;
    clear: both;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.wrapper #container #list {
    width: 420px;-->should be dynamically
    margin: 0 auto; --> only works when setting width
}
.wrapper #container #list .up {
    font-size: 11px;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: right; 
    display: inline;
}
.wrapper .navigation {
    font-size: 10px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 5px;
}
.wrapper .nav li {
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 15px;
    list-style: none;
}
```

so if there is someone who knows how to deal with that i really would appreciate.

thanks alot.

UPDATE:

thanks for answering this question for so far. using:

> display: inline-block;

on that container that should be centered works great.

Comment: Give each version a different width?

Comment: thats how it works at the moment. but i would like to know if there is an other way to do so... without testing, checking, correcting...

Comment: Using a pipe (`|`) instead of a border-left or border-right on actual content containing `li`s?

Comment: i think it is faster than creating an own css rule and adding into the ul. thats because you would have 4 borders but only 3 are used to be ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `display: inline-block`. See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/orig/xrh2T/)

```css
.wrapper #container  {
    /* ... */
    text-align: center;
}
.wrapper #container #list {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: hello and thanks for answering this question. for the first version it works fine. the second will be a problem. i updated my question. thanks.

Comment: If you have 3 `ul`s then all of them should be `inline-block`. In any case, it would be easier and more fun to help you if you create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) that shows the problem.

Comment: hello, i saw  that i have missed a dot to declare a class. thats why it has been displayed wrong. thanks alot for your help.

Comment: This centers the text inside the divs to the center, i'd like to center the divs not the text inside of them.